# Heroku login issue; Salesforce cannot complete request

Tags: authentication, heroku, salesforce

when I try to login to my Heroku account, after I enter my 2FA code, I get the green 'checkmark' as usual, but afterwards I am greeted with a Salesforce error screen, saying 'Problem Approving Your Request'.

[Error Message Salesforce](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVN7e.png)

I have tried multiple times over the span of an hour, but I still get the same error...

Is it an issue on my side? or is something broken at Heroku?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got this exact problem when using Waterfox. I switched to Chrome and was able to log in. If you're using a non-tracking kind of browser that might be the problem.